# Return newly allocated array

Tags: c++

In C++ local variables are getting destroyed when function leaves its scope.

```
int* doubleValue(int x)
{
    int value = x * 2;
    return &value; // return nValue by address here
} // value destroyed here
```

But I tried the following functions and seems both versions of function `allocateArray`
works well

```
int* allocateArray(int size)
{
    return new int[size];
}

int* allocateArrayVar(int size)
{
    int* var = new int[size];
    return var;
}//I expected memory for var would be deallocated here

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    {
    int* ar1 = allocateArray(10);
    ar1[0] = 1;// I can write into memory
    int* ar2 = allocateArrayVar(10);
    ar2[0] = 2;// I can write into memory
    }
}
```

Is there any difference between `allocateArray` and `allocateArrayVar` ?
And why `allocateArrayVar` does work but `doubleValue()` does not?

Comment: Neither `allocate*` function returns the address of a local variable, unlike `doubleValue`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between the two functions.

However, the comment in your code is a little misleading:

> I expected memory for `var` would be deallocated here

The point of using `new` is so your memory isn't deallocated once it goes out of scope. While true that `var` is "deallocated", it is not the case that the data that is pointed at (i.e., `*var`) is deallocated.

The programmer, in this case *you*, needs to manually deallocate the memory that was allocated by use of `new`. This is how you can do that:

```
void dellocateArray(int* arr) {
  delete[] arr;
}
```

The reason `allocateArrayVar` works but `doubleValue` does not comes from this distinction between who manages the memory:

- When something is allocated with `new` (or `malloc`, etc.), it is created on the **heap**, and is thus allocated until the programmer deallocates it with `delete` (or `free`, etc).
- All other instantiations are done on the **stack** and will be deallocated once it goes out of scope. Because the memory can be reclaimed, there's no guarantee that that memory address will contain what you expect.

Comment: The difference is between "pointer" and "pointee". `var` is indeed deallocated, but `*var` is not.

Comment: I guess the popular misconception comes from the overly loose language where people talk about "deleting a pointer". But that's really just slang, caused by the fact that the `delete` expression really does take a pointer operand. But it takes that operand *by value*, and what's being deleted is the pointee, not the pointer. Ironically, `delete` uses C-style reference semantics :-)

Comment: I hope the edit is a little truer. :) Thanks for keeping me honest.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between `allocateArray` and `allocateArrayVar`.
`doubleValue` returns a pointer to a local variable, which will be destroyed when the function returns (ie, it goes out of scope), and so the pointer becomes invalid. However, when you use the `new` operator, you are allocating memory on the heap, which ends up meaning that the memory stays valid until you call `delete` on it (which you really should be doing to avoid memory leaks).

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion stems from your definition of "local variable".

When you write the following code:

```
int* allocateArrayVar(int size)
{
    int* var = new int[size];
    return var;
}
```

Yes, you're returning a copy of a local variable `var`, but the value of `var` is the memory address to which the array was allocated. When memory is allocated with `new`, it is stored on the heap, which is not deallocated until you manually call `delete`.

So when the caller of `allocateArrayVar` receives a return value, it is still getting a valid memory address, even though `int* var` itself no longer exists.

Contrast this approach with

```
int* doubleValue(int x)
{
    int value = x * 2;
    return &value; // return nValue by address here
} // value destroyed here
```

Where `int value` is allocated on **the stack**. Stack memory does get deallocated after the function call completes, so the return value here is invalid (it's referring to a memory address on the stack, not the heap).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is no difference between `allocateArray` and `allocateArrayVar` in case of the result. If you want to know if there are differences in program's way of working, try to compile the version with first and then with the second function without optimization and with option that produces assembly code. And compare them ;)

If you are using `new` operator, the OS is allocating memory on the so called heap - the place which does not belong to any of the functions.
There is only one way to deallocate such kind of memory: to use `delete` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding returning references, returning reference to local variables is a bad idea (won't work) because local variables go out of scope when the function terminates.

In such situations it is better to return objects (pointers included) as memory allocated using `new` is stored in heap store, which has its lifetime as long as it is manually deleted using `delete` operator.

Reference: C++ Primer. Simply love that book :)